# How to assign variable when creating PHP array with key and value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$data = array(
    'uid' => 'key',
    'zip' => 'STRING_VARIABLE',

    "school" => array( 
        array("sid" => "STRING_VARIABLE", "qty" => NUMERIC_VARIABLE),
            array("strSrchSchool" => array(
            "name" => "STRING_VARIABLE", 
            "address" => "STRING_VARIABLE", 
        ), 
        "students" => NUMERIC_VARIABLE) 
    ),
    "sort" => "default"
);
```

Above array is a part of API call. I want dynamic values at places where I have mentioned 'STRING_VARIABLE' & 'NUMERIC_VARIABLE'. So I want to write PHP variables there and tried few different things of concatenation but none is working.

When I call API With different tries for above PHP variables, it gives below error.

> array(2) { ["status"]=> string(5) "error" ["error"]=> string(62) "Error parsing JSON object, check format and object definition." }

So please let me know what is correct method to write PHP variable directly at above mentioned places when  creating PHP array.

Comment: Can you clarify what "Part of the API call" this is, and describe a bit about the workflow surrounding it? It appears that your error could be resolved by adding a `json_decode()` (if you are receiving data) or a `json_encode` if you are passing it. You can try adding a `$data = json_encode()` data after your array definition and seeing if that helps, but I would need more context to provide a proper answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special.

Just write the name of the variable.

```
$zip = '252354';
$data = array(
    'uid' => 'key',
    'zip' => $zip,

    "school" => array( 
        array("sid" => "STRING_VARIABLE", "qty" => NUMERIC_VARIABLE),
            array("strSrchSchool" => array(
            "name" => "STRING_VARIABLE", 
            "address" => "STRING_VARIABLE", 
        ), 
        "students" => NUMERIC_VARIABLE) 
    ),
    "sort" => "default"
);
```

And so on you can write as many variables inside the array as you wish.